# Gibberish when putting non-English string in CouchBase JSON document

Tags: asp.net, json, serialization, couchbase

I am trying to insert a .NET serialized JSON document to CouchBase but get gibberish with non-English characters.

I've tried to put:

```
name = " الفورية مترجم نصوص مجاني إلى "
```

But I get:

```
"name": " ״§„ˆ״±״© …״×״±״¬… †״µˆ״µ …״¬״§† ״¥„‰ ",
```

When viewing it in CouchBase administration page.

Any solution?

I am using ASP.NET 4.5 and latest CouchBase API with CouchBase 2.0 beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also noted on http://www.couchbase.com/forums/thread/gibrish-non-english-characters-using-c-client-and-coucbase-2-0-beta, but copied here for reference:

Hi Idanm

The .NET client stores strings using UTF-8. Are you seeing the data coming out of the client correctly, or are the mixed up strings in the admin console?

Also, you can try the new extension methods that use Newtonsoft.JSON for Json serialization. In the .NET Couchbase Client Beta, you'll find Couchbase.Extensions with the following class:

```
public static class CouchbaseClientExtensions
{
    public static bool StoreJson(this CouchbaseClient client, StoreMode storeMode, string key, object value)
    {
        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
        return client.Store(storeMode, key, json);
    }

    public static T GetJson<T>(this CouchbaseClient client, string key) where T : class
    {
        var json = client.Get<string>(key);
        return json == null ? null : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
    }
}
```

It seems possible that the Encoding.Default.GetBytes in the extensions you're using might be at fault here...

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not familiar with the Couchbase storage system, you're definitely running into a text encoding issue. I'd check that your JSON serializer is serializing to UTF-8 encoding, as well as ensuring that you're specifying UTF-8 encoding on the Couchbase side. Check their APIs and storage types to ensure that they are UTF-8 based.